# How do I use the ShowLegends function to produce a legend for my framed graphic?

Tags: plotting, formatting, legending

I'm new to this site and new to Mathematica as you can see from my question. I'm also new to programming, btw.

I'm trying to produce a legend for my plot which I've coded as follows:

```
Needs["PlotLegends`"]
ds1 = {{0, 0.53}, {10, 1.00}, {20, 2.19}, {35, 3.61}};
ds2 = {{0, 0.52}, {10, 0.91}, {20, 1.97}, {35, 3.09}};
ds3 = {{0, ds1[[1, 2]] - ds2[[1, 2]]}, 
       {10, ds1[[2, 2]] - ds2[[2, 2]]}, 
       {20, ds1[[3, 2]] - ds2[[3, 2]]}, 
       {35, ds1[[4, 2]] - ds2[[4, 2]]}
      };
mf1 = LinearModelFit[ds1, x, x];
mf2 = LinearModelFit[ds2, x, x];
mf3 = LinearModelFit[ds3, x, x];
m1 = mf1["BestFit"]; m2 = mf2["BestFit"]; m3 = mf3["BestFit"];

Show[
  {
    ListPlot[{ds1, ds2, ds3}, 
       PlotMarkers -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red, Orange}
    ], 
    Plot[{m1, m2, m3}, {x, 0, 35}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red, Orange}]
  }, 
  Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"Time (min)","Inorganic Phosphate Concentration (mM)"},
  ImageSize -> {400, 300}
]
```

So, I'd like to use the `ShowLegend` function to have the legend displayed outside of the frame. I know that I can use the `LegendPosition` function to do this.

My problem, however, is the tags. How do I get the legend to show the names of the plots (ds1, ds2, ds3, m1, m2, and m3)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this?

```
ShowLegend[
 Show[{ListPlot[{ds1, ds2, ds3}, PlotMarkers -> Automatic, 
    PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red, Orange}], 
   Plot[{m1, m2, m3}, {x, 0, 35}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red, Orange}]}, 
  Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"Time (min)", 
    "Inorganic Phosphate Concentration (mM)"}, ImageSize -> {500}],
 {{
   {Style["\[FilledCircle]", 12, Blue], "ds1"},
   {Style["\[FilledSquare]", 12, Red], "ds2"},
   {Style["\[FilledDiamond]", 12, Orange], "ds3"},
   {Graphics@{Blue, Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}]}, "m1"},
   {Graphics@{Red, Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}]}, "m2"},
   {Graphics@{Orange, Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}]}, "m3"}
   }, LegendPosition -> {1, -0.4}}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer. It was what I was looking for.